# Try block can throw nothing, nonetheless there is no compile-time error occured

Tags: java, exception

In the program:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        try{} catch (NumberFormatException e){ }
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/mulwwo)

Actually, the [JLS 11.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3) describes behavior in such cases:

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked
>   exception class `E1` and it is not the case that the try block
>   corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class
>   that is a subclass or superclass of `E1`, unless `E1` is `Exception` or a
>   superclass of `Exception`.

In my case the `catch` clause can catch [NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) that is neither `Exception` nor superclass of `Exception`. Try block can throw nothing, because there are no statements in there. So, why the code is compiled fine?

Comment: Checked  and unchecked exceptions are explained in detail on the official Java SE tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch **checked exception**...

`NumberFormatException` is **not** a checked exception. It's a sub-class of `IllegalArgumentException`, which is a sub-class of `RuntimeException`. Therefore the entire clause you quoted from the JLS does not apply.

Replace `NumberFormatException` with some exception that is not a sub-class of `RuntimeException` (for example, `IOException`), and you'll get a compile-time error.

Comment: Maybe you give an example?

Comment: @St.Antario try catching `IOException`.

Comment: @St.Antario replace `NumberFormatException` with a checked exception - for example `IOException` - and you'll get compilation error.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It's funny how we thought about the same example :)

Comment: @Eran I suppose it's because the `IOException` is the bane of every Java developer's existence...

Comment: @BoristheSpider - it isn't the bane of >>my<< existence :-)

Comment: @StephenC you _must_ be lying... ;)

Comment: @BoristheSpider - No.  I just have a good sense of proportion.